# How do I repopulate dynamically added asp.net table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp.net Table and a 'Add' Button. On Each add button click I have add usercontrol in asp.net table. But when I click any  other control on the the form my asp.net table disappear. How can I put Asp.net table in viewstate??

Comment: You can keep track of what user controls are added in a session variable and then re-build them in Page_Init event

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Page_Load, Use

```
    override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
         LoadDynamicControls()
    }

    private void LoadDynamicControls()
    {
        //Load your table here
    }
```